# Merge 2 arrays in PHP in a specific way by taking one key from each

Tags: php, arrays

Struggling to find the logic to merge 2 arrays in a specific way for example I have

```
array('lemons', 'oranges', 'grapes', 'pineapples');
```

and

```
array('carrots', 'onions', 'cabbage');
```

and I want to end up with

```
array('lemons', 'carrots', 'oranges', 'onions', 'grapes', 'cabbage' 'pineapples');
```

I.e to merge them in a one from each way rather than just together at the end and start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most sophisticated answer, but this is what I have come up with.

```
$array1 = array('lemons', 'oranges', 'grapes', 'pineapples');
$array2 = array('carrots', 'onions', 'cabbage');
$iterator = 0;
// Continue until the end of both arrays
while (!empty($array1) || !empty($array2)) {
    // If iterator is odd then we want the second array, or if array one is empty
    if ($iterator++ % 2 == 1 && !empty($array2) || empty($array1)) {
        $array3[] = array_shift($array2);
    } else {
        $array3[] = array_shift($array1);
    }
}
var_dump($array3);
```

Output:

```
array('lemons', 'carrots', 'oranges', 'onions', 'grapes', 'cabbage' 'pineapples');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$x = 0;
while ($x < max(count($fruit), count($veg))) {
  if (isset($fruit[$x])) {
    $merged[] = $fruit[$x];
  }
  if (isset($veg[$x])) {
    $merged[] = $veg[$x];
  }
  $x++;
}
```

something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the indexes (from 0 to max(count($array1), count($array2))), then in the loop statement, append the indexed element of each array to a new one, if they are set.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$ar1 = array('lemons', 'oranges', 'grapes', 'pineapples');
$ar2 = array('carrots', 'onions', 'cabbage');

function mergeCustom($ar1, $ar2) {
    $newAr = array();
    foreach ($ar1 as $key => $item) {
        array_push($newAr, $item);
        if (!empty($ar2[$key])) {
            array_push($newAr, $ar2[$key]);
        }
    }
    // if length of second array is greater then first one
    while(!empty($ar2[$key])) {
        array_push($newAr, $ar2[$key]);
        $key++;
    }
    return $newAr;
}

var_dump(mergeCustom($ar1, $ar2), mergeCustom($ar2, $ar1));
```

Output will be:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "lemons"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "carrots"
  [2]=>
  string(7) "oranges"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "onions"
  [4]=>
  string(6) "grapes"
  [5]=>
  string(7) "cabbage"
  [6]=>
  string(10) "pineapples"
}
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "carrots"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "lemons"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "onions"
  [3]=>
  string(7) "oranges"
  [4]=>
  string(7) "cabbage"
  [5]=>
  string(6) "grapes"
  [6]=>
  string(6) "grapes"
  [7]=>
  string(10) "pineapples"
}
```